# Class 'MongoDB\BSON\Regex' not found

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mongodb

I trying example from php.net: -http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-regex.php

when performing a code below in php

```
$regex = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex ( '^Al');
$cursor = $collection->find(array('name' => $regex));
//iterate through the cursor
```

then php show me error  Class 'MongoDB\BSON\Regex' not found 
please help me how can i solve this query

Comment: Well, you need to somehow include the class definition to be able to use that class. How did you do that?

Comment: how can i include this class MongoDB\BSON\Regex

Comment: please give example  class MongoDB\BSON\Regex use

Comment: You need the class definition for that class ("the code"), then you `include()` that file before using the class.

Comment: Backslash??  Wrong syntax, I think.

Comment: Give me example or class new MongoDB\BSON\Regex to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You may find that only Eclipse is marking it as a problem, but when you run it on the web server it is fine.

If this is the case then your answer is here:
[How to have eclipse resolve php classes in MongoDB\BSON namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316371/how-to-have-eclipse-resolve-php-classes-in-mongodb-bson-namespace)