# How to have eclipse resolve php classes in MongoDB\BSON namespace?

Tags: php, php-mongodb

After many comes and goes I managed to install the MongoDB Driver for PHP 5.6 and made it work on OSX El Capitan. (The way it worked was using *Homebrew*)

To start working on a project I created the folder for the project and using *Composer* installed the required packages I needed. Between theese packages I required *mongodb/mongodb* which is the recomended [mongo php library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) to use by [the php Manual](http://docs.php.net/set.mongodb) on line and in [the driver github page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver).

The problem I found is that Eclipse is resolving the classes in the \MongoDB\ namespace but not in the \MongoDB\BSON\ namespace. If I check what *Composer* installed in the *vendor* folder I am able to see that the \MongoDB\BSON\ classes in fact are missing. On the other hand if I run the program in the PHP included webserver, it executes as expected.

So my question is how can do or what am I missing for Eclipse to find the missing classes. Are they defined somewhere else?

If this is not possible because they are compiled into a binary library and I have no way to resolve them, Is there any way to have Eclipse not showing these particular classes as mistakes?

Example of class that runs ok in the webserver, but is highlighted as an error in Eclipse:

```
$fecha_creacion  = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime();
```

Comment: Can you search your project folder for MongoDB\BSON? It may be in another package - not the one you are looking in, and eclipse is not recognizing the enclosing folder as a PSR namespace root.

Comment: The vendor folder is well structured, I checked for the mongodb folders and these classes are not there.

Comment: Yes. It's entirely possible for another folder, perhaps even outside of the vendor tree, to have the files as well. I'm merely suggesting searching all of your project files for the BSON namespace to see if it's there somewhere you (and eclipse) don't expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading [this post](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/issues/55) and not finding anything newer on the subject I arrived to the conclusion that developers of the driver don't provide the php sources and leave it to the IDE developers to provide STUBs for the different fuctions of the driver in a way the IDE can recognize the functions and provide syntax checking and documentations popups.

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328805/phpstorm-how-to-add-method-stubs-from-a-pecl-library-that-phpstorm-doesnt-curr/30329412#30329412), I finally ended up finding a JetBrains GitHub where there are many different stubs for PHPStrom, this [one](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/mongodb/mongodb.php) among them.

So I copied the file and added it to my project as part of the sources. And that solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering your own question, it really helped me out.